# how to enable javascript in winforms application?

Tags: javascript, winforms, webbrowser-control

How to enable javascript in winforms application?
I am using web browser control and I want to check if javascript disable on browser then I want to enable into my win application.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170944/how-can-you-programmatically-detect-if-javascript-is-enabled-disabled-in-a-windo for more details

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, you use WebKit Control

Comment: i am new in winforms app.
how can i use that?

Comment: I would suggest googling around the toping using WebKit