# Client side validations not working in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-9, client-side-validation

I just created mvc 4 Application .In that application I have a form to insert department. for that form I'm using client side validations.

these client side validations properly working in Firefox and Chrome , but not in IE 9 (Internet Explorer)

This is my model class

```
 public partial class tbl_hec_Department
    {
        public tbl_hec_Department()
        {
            this.tbl_hec_level_of_Study = new HashSet<tbl_hec_level_of_Study>();
            this.tbl_hec_Programme = new HashSet<tbl_hec_Programme>();
        }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Department ID")]
        [Remote("doesDepartment_IDExist", "HEC", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Department ID already exists.")]
        public string Department_ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Name of Department")]
        public string Name_of_Department { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [DisplayName("Telephone Number")]
        //[StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a minimum of {2} characters", MinimumLength = 6)]
        public string Contact_General_Line { get; set; }

        //[StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a minimum of {2} characters", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DisplayName("Fax Number")]
        public string Contact_Fax_Number { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address")]
        [DisplayName("Email Address")]
        public string Contact_Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select the {0}")]
        [DisplayName("University / Institute")]
        public string HEI_ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select the {0}")]
        [DisplayName("College")]
        public string College_ID { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Status")]
        public Nullable<bool> Status { get; set; }

        public string Create_By { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Create_Date { get; set; }
        public string Update_By { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Update_Date { get; set; }

        public virtual tbl_hec_College tbl_hec_College { get; set; }
        public virtual tbl_hec_University tbl_hec_University { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<tbl_hec_level_of_Study> tbl_hec_level_of_Study { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<tbl_hec_Programme> tbl_hec_Programme { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

theses are the scripts files in Scripts Folder

[image]

this is how i render script files in layout files

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/raphael-min.js")        
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/morris.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.sparkline.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js")    
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.knob.js")        
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/daterangepicker.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js")       
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/icheck.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/app.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/dashboard.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/demo.js")
```

Comment: Where is the client side script?

Comment: @colecmc - probably using unobtrusive validations.

Comment: If the JS is the problem, where is the JS?

Comment: scripts Im getting from layout file

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that in client machine browser java script is disabled. First you check whether java script is enabled or disabled in client browser. You can check it programatically using this code.

```
    public static bool IsJavascriptEnabled( )
{
    bool retVal = true;
    //get the registry key for Zone 3(Internet Zone)
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3", true);

    if (key != null)
    {
        Object value = key.GetValue(DWORD_FOR_ACTIVE_SCRIPTING, VALUE_FOR_ENABLED);
        if( value.ToString().Equals(VALUE_FOR_DISABLED) )
        {
            retVal = false;
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

You can also visit this link [How to check java scxript in client browser enabled or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170944/how-can-you-programmatically-detect-if-javascript-is-enabled-disabled-in-a-windo)

Comment: but few of validations are working as shown in that picture . how that happening